# ASP.Net error responses are empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

After transferring from a web site to a web application project we've run into some issues regarding exceptions.

When an exception occurs first of all the debugger doesn't pick it up. Doesn't break, just continues. Breakpoints are triggered!

The result to the browser is literally blank, no result at all (not even an empty html page, just nothing).

The Application_Error in Gobal.asax.cs is triggered and the exceptions are processed to our webservice that tracks them, but not reported to the browser or caught by VS.

Does anyone have an idea what might cause this?

**EDIT: Some extra information**

- Visual Studio 2010
- .Net Framework 4.0
- ASP.Net Development Server
- Windows 7 64-bits

**More info:**

The problem occurs with my co-workers too, as well as on the live version.

Comment: Does it reach the web service, i doubt that ?

Comment: I've had a similar issue when the framework version being used is innacurate in IIS. Are you using IIS or the ASP.NET Dev Server?

Comment: Windows-,IIS- and Framework/VS-Version might be heplful.

Comment: @V4Vendetta The exceptions do reach the web service.

Comment: Do project references work correctly ?

Comment: Yes, they do work properly, and the problem is solved now xD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after 4 hours of searching what causes it we found it.

Turns out a co-worker added this line at the end of the Application_Error in the Global.asax:

```
Server.ClearError();
```

Cause at a Microsoft course our teacher said you always have to clear errors after retrieving them. Turns out this wasn't a good idea, since the .Net Framework doesn't have any more errors to handle then. And it doesn't render an error page.

The problem is solved now, thanks for the replies.